# MFC DDX_Text() double Input - CString %f output different?

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2019

I have an MFC app using `DDX_Text()` on a double value.  I enter `.0000001` as the value, when I go back in it is `1e-07` (presumably using %g), if I save it that way, it stays `1e-07`.

Now if I take a `CString` and `.Format(_T("%f"), m_Double)` the output is `0.000000` (it's missing the 1).  The actual value of the m_Double as reported by debug mode hovering the mouse cursor over it is: `9.9999999999999995e-08`

Using Visual Studio 2022 (Solution using Visual Studio 2019 target).

How do I get the output to be .0000001 ?

Comment: A double value cannot represent the decimal value .0000001. If you need accurate decimals you cannot use floating point types.

Comment: Pretty simple, the "1" digit is 7 places after the decimal point, while `.Format()` with "%f" formatting but without a precision specifier appears to use a default precision of 6, so 0.0000001 is rounded to 0.000000. So what's the question exactly, `DDX_Text()` not working as you would want or how `.Format()` works? In the former case there's not much you can do, only write a new `DDX_Double()` routine, with the desired formatting.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou Yes, the C++ standard says that is the default precision "[f]or a, A, e, E, f and F specifiers: this is the number of digits to be printed after the decimal point **(by default, this is 6)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your question can be split into two parts

1. Displaying more than 6 digits

If this is the real question, then for that the answer is to use Format Specifiers. According to the [documentation provided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class?view=msvc-170#format),

> Writes formatted data to a CStringT in the same way that sprintf_s formats data into a C-style character array.

So in order to format your string, you could just use format specifiers. In your case, something resembling %.8f

```cpp
.Format(_T("%.8f"), m_Double)
```

2. The second part of the question is regarding IEEE Floating Point's accuracy.

Here @iinspectable is very correct in that they cannot be represented accurately.

However you could be [helped by rounding which occurs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sprintf-sprintf-l-swprintf-swprintf-l-swprintf-l?view=msvc-170)

> Starting in Windows 10 version 2004 (build 19041), the printf family of functions prints exactly representable floating point numbers according to the IEEE 754 rules for rounding. In previous versions of Windows, exactly representable floating point numbers ending in '5' would always round up. IEEE 754 states that they must round to the closest even digit (also known as "Banker's Rounding"). For example, both printf("%1.0f", 1.5) and printf("%1.0f", 2.5) should round to 2. Previously, 1.5 would round to 2 and 2.5 would round to 3. This change only affects exactly representable numbers. For example, 2.35 (which, when represented in memory, is closer to 2.35000000000000008) continues to round up to 2.4. Rounding done by these functions now also respects the floating point rounding mode set by fesetround. Previously, rounding always chose FE_TONEAREST behavior. This change only affects programs built using Visual Studio 2019 version 16.2 and later. To use the legacy floating point rounding behavior, link with 'legacy_stdio_float_rounding.obj`.